# Using TCPDF library, how do I combine text and barcodes so that they are written as a unit?

Tags: pdf, qr-code, tcpdf

I am using the TCPDF library to add QR codes to existing PDF's, and I have created these two functions, one of which writes the QR code (overriding the original function), and the other which writes a QR code "id" above it. I would like to write the ID both above and below the QR code. The ID when written below the QR code would be rotated 180 degrees (inverted horiz and vert). For example:

```
MM12122
+-----+
|     |
+-----+
55151WW
```

Here are my functions:

```
public function write2DBarcode($code, $type = 'QRCODE,L', $x = 192, $y = 25, $w = 20, $h = 20, $style = QR_CODE_STYLE, $align = 'N', $distort = false)
{
    return parent::write2DBarcode($code, $type, $x, $y, $w, $h, $style, $align, $distort);
}

public function writeQRID($id, $w = 20, $h = 10, $x = 195, $y = 19 ) {
    // print ID on page
    $this->SetFont('ocrb');
    $this->SetTextColor(0,0,0);
    $this->SetFillColor(255,255,255); // doesn't work!?
    $this->SetFontSize(9);
    $this->WriteHTMLCell($w, $h, $x, $y, 'QR' . $id,'','',true) ;
}
```

Right now I'm using absolute x-y coordinates to write the ID and the QR code, so my question is: How do I make these three writes as a group or "unit" so that I can just reference the top left position on the document? The QR code is added to the top right of the document, right at the edge. I would like to be able to change the size of the text or code or position of the group without having to worry about the other elements overlapping or not being visible.